# How to get the filename and file path of files already stored in a folder?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have uploaded files of different types(image, pptx, video and docx) using Multer in the folder named 'uploads'.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');

/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    });
});
```

Now the uploaded files are being stored in 'uploads' folder like /uploads/demo.pptx

I need to fetch these and send the filepath or url of the stored files and send as a response to client so they can access to watch or download it.

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: Gaurav Srivastava, I have edited the post. Please do look at it

Comment: console.log the response after upload see if it returns filepath or url and let me know so i can help you with the code

Comment: I'm getting a very long response about 500 lines. Part of the response is like this `file:
      { fieldname: 'file',
        originalname: 'css3net.pptx',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.
presentation',
        destination: './uploads/',
        filename: 'css3net.pptx',
        path: 'uploads\\css3net.pptx',
        size: 2202892 } },
  locals: {},
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  statusCode: 200 }`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, files stored in DB when you need to do more than just serve them and upload new files. For this proposes, you could save only file's metadata to DB(such as size, type, path, name). However if you for some reason still need to store files in DB, MongoDB have [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) component and provides a documentation about working with this component.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:-

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs(//credential here);

var uploaded_file=db.collection("uploaded_file");


var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');

/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }else{
                  uploaded_file.insert(res.file,function(err, saved) {// i am asuming res.file have the information you needed to send
                if(err){
                    console.log("Unexpected error occurred during insertion in database:"+err);
                }else{
                     res.send({error_code:0,file_info:res.file});
                     res.end();
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```